# Change axis range into latitude and longitude using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, latitude-longitude

How can I use yaxis and xaxis, which I want and that are not correlated with data in the plot?
For example, I want to plot the world map as an image using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(world_map)
```

As a result, I got xaxis: 0...image_size_x from the left to the rigth and yaxis: 0...image_size_y from top to bottom.
What do I need to to do to change its axis range into latitude and longitude formats? Thus the figure axis should contain degrees (from 90 to -90) on the both fields (x and y) regardless of what its real data plotted in the figure.
Setting

```
pylab.ylim([90,-90])
```

will shift the image to the bottom by 90 pixels and reduced the y-dimension of the image into the scale of image_size_y/90. So it'll not work because xlim/ylim works with data, plotted in the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (based on your post) the image is fine but the axis labels are off, try playing around with this, which will manually implement the axis labels:

```
plt.figure(1)     
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#... do your stuff
#need to figure out your image size divided by the number of labels you want
#FOR EXample, if image size was 180, and you wanted every second coordinate labeled:
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(0,180,2)]) #python3 code to create 90 tick marks
ax.set_xticklabels([-i for i in range(-90,90,2)]) #python3 code to create 90 labels
#DO SAME FOR Y
```

The trick im using is to figure out how many labels you want (here, its 90: 180/2), add the tickmarks evenly in the range (0,imagesize), then manually do the labels. Here is a general formula:

```
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(0,IMAGE_SIZE,_EVERY_XTH_COORD_LABELED)]) #python3 code to create 90 tick marks
ax.set_xticklabels([-i for i in range(-90,90,EVERY_XTH_COORD_LABELED)]) #python3 code to create 90 labels
```

Comment: `set_xticklabels` is almost always a bad idea.  It decouples your labels from your data.  Better to use `FuncFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Use the `extent` keyword with `imshow`.

In code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subaxis(111)
ax.imshow(world_map, extent=[-180,180,-90,90], aspect='auto')
```

If your map is then upside down, add the keyword argument `origin='lower'` to the `imshow`. That `aspect='auto'` is needed to make the map scalable in both dimensions independently. (The rest of the extra rows with `add_subaxis` are just to make the code more object-oriented, the real beef is in the keyword arguments.)

If `imshow` is not given the extents of the image, it thinks that you'll want to have each pixel centered at positions (0,0), (0,1), ..., (Nx-1, Ny-1), and then the image extents will start from (-.5, -.5).

Comment: It works good. But the thing is I use a [mercator projection map](http://postimg.org/image/hrur2d06j/), where each 20 degrees of latitude (y dimension) has different its size in pixels. So I think the better way will be using something like Tommy said below.